# Using data from previous query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I want use a query like such

```
SELECT personId
FROM Person p 
Inner Join address a on p.personId=a.personId
WHERE(a.created > GETDATE() -10)
```

I want to then use this data to filter this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts a
WHERE a.person /*is in the results of the previous query */
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick (assuming you have the column personId in your account table).

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts a
WHERE a.personId in (
                SELECT DISTINCT personId
                FROM Person p 
                Inner Join address a on p.personId=a.personId
                WHERE(a.created > DATEADD(d,-10,GETDATE())))
```

Alternatively, rather than using a subquery you could just join the 3 tables directly:

```
SELECT
    C.*
FROM
    accounts C
INNER JOIN
    Person P ON P.personId = C.personId
INNER JOIN
    [Address] A ON A.personId = P.PersonId
WHERE
    A.created > DATEADD(d,-10,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks, fastest response ever. Will give it a shot

Comment: Haha, must have just come on to the site as you posted.

Comment: This is not a good answer for SQL Server 2008 when a CTE is more maintainable/readable and benefits from a JOIN vs an IN clause, but no down vote since it works.

Comment: Yeah, good point re: maintainability - I'm a big fan of CTEs actually, was just trying to keep my answer at the most basic level.  I agree though - a CTE would be the most elegant solution here.

Answer (score 3):

A nice feature in SQL Server 2008 is the Common Table Expression (CTE). It's basically an in-line view and makes the query that is actually returning the data much cleaner to read.

```
WITH people
AS
(
SELECT personId
FROM Person p 
Inner Join address a on p.personId=a.personId
WHERE(a.created > GETDATE() -10)
)

SELECT * 
FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN people p ON a.personId = p.personId
```

Comment: I like this sytax, how does it fare performance wise? Are you hitting the DB more doing this?

Comment: Performance-wise, CTEs are performance neutral. The SQL Server engine will in-line the CTE into one big final query, but it's much easier for a developer to debug and maintain - especially when you need to GROUP BY an aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts a
WHERE a.person IN 
(
SELECT personId
FROM Person p 
Inner Join address a on p.personId=a.personId
WHERE(a.created > GETDATE() -10)
);
```

Comment: This is not a good answer for SQL Server 2008 when a CTE is more maintainable/readable and benefits from a JOIN vs an IN clause, but no down vote since it works.

Comment: @HardCode i come from a mainly Oracle Background - do you have an example of a CTE?

Comment: Oracle has CTE's as well.  (With the same `WITH` syntax used in HardCode's answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
begin
with Results AS
(
SELECT *
FROM Person p 
Inner Join address a on p.personId=a.personId
WHERE(a.created > GETDATE() -10)
)
END

SELECT * 
FROM accounts a
WHERE a.person IN (select person from Results )
```